# Reload annotations in a map view

Tags: ios, annotations, mkmapview, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am adding annotations as hardcoded values into the method

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation

     CLLocationCoordinate2D coords1;
     coords1.latitude = 40.579754;
     coords1.longitude = -120.1303229;

     MKPointAnnotation *annotationPoint1 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
     annotationPoint1.coordinate = coords1;
     annotationPoint1.title = @"TJ11234";
     annotationPoint1.subtitle = @"Power Failure \n Start Time:12hrs 30min \n End Time:14hrs ";

     [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotationPoint1];
```

with values of lats and longitude hardcode intially its loading fine, but when I go to another page and come back to the page the annotations are not loading. What should I do to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

`mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:` is called whenever a new location update is received by the map view. Check the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html).

If you want to set annotation when your map is shown, you can place your code in `viewDidAppear` or similar.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated]

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coords1;
    coords1.latitude = 40.579754;
    coords1.longitude = -120.1303229;

    MKPointAnnotation *annotationPoint1 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    annotationPoint1.coordinate = coords1;
    annotationPoint1.title = @"TJ11234";
    annotationPoint1.subtitle = @"Power Failure \n Start Time:12hrs 30min \n End Time:14hrs ";

    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotationPoint1];
}
```

Hope this helps.